# Merge table rows based on row text and class

Tags: javascript, html, merge, html-table

I have found this function [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518034/962734) and it almost perfectly suits my needs. The function iterates through the first column of a table, and row merges similar values. Then, it iterates through the next column, and row merges those values as well, while taking into account the merges of the column before it. In this way, it perfectly suits what I need.

```
function MergeCommonRows2(table, firstOnly) {
    var firstColumnBrakes = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= table.find('th').length; i++) {
        var previous = null, cellToExtend = null, rowspan = 1;
        table.find("td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function (index, el) {
            if (previous == $(el).text() && $(el).text() !== "" && $.inArray(index, firstColumnBrakes) === -1) {
                $(el).addClass('hidden');
                cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", (rowspan = rowspan + 1));
            } else {
                if (firstOnly == 'first only') {
                    if (i === 1)
                        firstColumnBrakes.push(index);
                } else {
                    if ($.inArray(index, firstColumnBrakes) === -1)
                        firstColumnBrakes.push(index);
                }
                rowspan = 1;
                previous = $(el).text();
                cellToExtend = $(el);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I wish to edit the function to consider classes as well. In other words, I wish to edit the function to first check the classes of the two rows being merged. And, even if they have the same value, if they have different classes, to NOT merge the rows. I have tried to edit the above function to do as much, but to no avail.

---

**UPDATE**

My attempts to edit the code were quite crude. Essentially, I put code before he `if` statement that adds a `hidden` class and said, to summarize, if `previous.getClass = current.getClass`, only then go onto the if statement that hides the class.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfdL4ay8/30/). I want to click the merge button and, since the "click me" cells have a different classes between them, I don't want them to merge.

Comment: Can you put a sample table (with some of the classes) and your code into jsfiddle.net? Will help get responses much quicker. Could also use some clarification on what exactly should be merged

Comment: ...or into Stack Snippets (aka Code Snippet in the question editor) so that we can run it without leaving Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, you may want to mention what you tried previously, so that we don't repeat the same problems you've already experienced.

Comment: Okay, so I have a jsFiddle. It is essentially being taken from the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492279/jquery-merge-table-rows-but-take-previous-columns-into-account and editing the "click me" cells. I added different classes to them. If you click the button "merge with previous column" or whatnot, they still merge. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfdL4ay8/30/

Comment: Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: You wrote: *"if they have different classes, to NOT merge the rows"*. What if both rows have a class `A` but only one has class `B`? What if one row don't have any class but the second one have? Also, some of the rows have classes `hidden` and `pernamently-hidden` while other rows doesn't...